# How do I create an SSIS package that executes a bat file

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, batch-file, ssis

I am trying to create a job in SQL Server Management Studio using an SSIS package to execute a bat file.  The bat file sets in motion an FTP transfer as well as file renaming and archiving.  I have tested the bat file and it executes properly with all steps completed.  The problem I am running into is with the SSIS package.  I am not a frequent user of Visual Studio so it is quite possible I am overlooking something.  On the control flow tab I added an "Execute process task".  I specified both the file path for the bat file and the working directory.  I verified this set up against other existing jobs we have in place that also execute bat files.  When I tell the job to run, it says it has completed successfully with no errors.  When I manually verify the results, the bat file has not been executed.  I do not know what I am overlooking here.  The SSIS package and the bat file reside on the same server, and the appropriate shares exist for the file transfer.  Any ideas as to what I may have missed would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it execute successfully when you run the process in VS?

Comment: Check folder permissions where the bat file is located.  Can pretty much guarantee that the SQL job agent doesn't have permission to run the bat.

Comment: Hi Aaron.  We have other jobs running bat files out of the same folder, so not a permissions issue.

Comment: Hi Jacob.  No, but that is because the package and files it is accessing reside on a different server than the one VS is on.  I couldn't tell you why, I inherited this network.

Comment: How you specified file path and bat file? Are they UNC, eg, \\server-name\shared-resource-pathname. It doesn't matter if VS and file are on the same server or not. You should always test SSIS package in VS before using it in the job.

Comment: Hi Wendy.  For the SSIS package, the path name is correct.  I did alter it previously as you suggest to test the package, however the appropriate shares do not exist between the two servers to allow the UNC path to work.

Comment: @Greg Are those other jobs executed as the same user as this one?  Although I don't understand your response to Jacob... I run packages that are stored on a shared drive from multiple different servers and can run the execute .bat files tasks in them just fine.  What happens if you run the task in the package?

Comment: Aaron, yes it the same user.  There is one created specifically for running jobs and reports so it doesn't have more permissions than it needs.  We have other jobs set up on the same server using the same folder that execute just fine.  For whatever reason, this one does not.  The only difference between the other SSIS packages and this one is that the other packages have more steps involved.  This one only needs to execute the bat file.  I am wondering if that is the problem, that it is too simple and something is missing that should be there?

Comment: To try to clarify again for everyone asking about package testing, Visual Studio is installed on server "A", while the project files, packages, and the folders they access are on server "B".  The necessary permissions and shares do not exist between server "A" and server "B" for me to test the package in Visual Studio.  I don't know why the network was set up this way, I inherited it from the last Network Admin.  I do understand the importance of being able to test, but it hasn't been an issue until now.

Comment: @Greg So then... if you open another package that has a .bat file and is working properly, and you execute that .bat file from the package, it will also fail?  But succeed if executed from the job?  I guess that kind of makes sense if you can't open the packages as the job account, and therefore lack the permissions in VS... But very unfortunate environment to inherit.

Comment: @Greg Anyway, without an error it's impossible to say what your problem is.  Since you have working packages on hand, compare every property of the Execute task in a working package to your current, not-working package.  Double-triple check permissions.  Compare security of a working .bat to the security of the new .bat.  Maybe something was inherited or changed on the old ones that you weren't informed about, making the folder permissions not good enough.  Check for typos, etc.  I'm still convinced it is a security issue since you aren't getting a job failure though.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Why not do this inside SSIS using the supplied FTP Task? In addition you can do all the file renaming you want using the File System Task.

FTP Task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/ftp-task

File System Task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/file-system-task

**Updated after latest comment:**

If the built-in component doesnt work for you, have you considered 3rd party components such as https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis

That component seems to use WinSCP as a backend

Comment: Hi Rachel.  Thanks for the idea, I'll have to read up on it.  I've never attempted that before.  Pretty much every job that does ftp is driven off of a bat file here.

Comment: After reading up on it, I see that the built in ftp is not secure.  For our industry, we must use secure ftp, which is apparently why all of our existing ftp jobs use bat files to execute an ftp program.

Comment: I updated my answer for another possibility. Personally speaking I always try to stay away from executing batch files whenever possible. However you may be unable to avoid that yourself.

Comment: Rachel, that's very nearly identical to our existing setup.  We use WinSCP.com instead of exe, but call upon it in the same manner essentially.  No issues until now.